# What kind of magic could people able to manipulate the 4th dimension do?

Tags: science-based, magic, super-powers, balancing-magic-systems, high-fantasy

In this world with renaissance-like technology wizards are able to "feels" creases in the 3D space and manipulate space in ways limited to their understanding of the 4D (wich is still not fully understood).
They are able to do wormhole transportation but the two ends of the wormhole are fixed to a specific geographical point and teleporting living things usually kills them.
Some plants also use this creases in space to teleport sap to the canopy so they are able to grow larger.
Opening one of this wormholes is difficult and takes time but perhaps other interactions with the 4th dimension are more easily done.
Besides teleportation and what I mentioned, what other kinds of things would be possible?

Comment: Hi Yzegem and welcome to Worldbuilding!  As it stands, this question is a hypothetical open-ended question about something with no basis in reality, so no meaningful answer is possible.  I recommend you check out the [help centre](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) to get an idea of the kind of question that will get a good answer.  If you want a particular answer, better-constrain your question (one answer, not many), and provide better details as to how your magic system works.  (Typically, the 4th dimension of spacetime is _time_.)

Comment: For now, I am voting to close this question as Opinion Based.  Once you have a better idea of what you want to ask, you can edit this question and it can be reviewed and reopened, should the consensus be that it should be closed.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi Yzegem! I agree that you really need a little better handle on what you're asking. We really can't tell you what things could be done in 4D space in your world until you yourself know more what that entails.  Do not worry about comments that complain about this not having a "basis in reality". We deal specifically in the unreal! But we do need a better understanding of your world and the magic system you're cooking up!

Comment: Tease apart the fundamentals of how your ability operates.  For example, "Some plants also use this creases in space to teleport sap to the canopy so they are able to grow larger."  The thing that's hard about transporting sap is that you have to lift it to a higher altitude, with more potential energy.  The fact that you say plants can leverage this tells me that the laws of physics as we know them fundamentally break down around your wormholes.  Conservation of energy doesn't appear to apply.  This tells you a lot about what can be done with such abilities.

Comment: Hello @Yzegem. For future reference, please be aware that asking open-ended and/or hypothetical questions is prohibited (see [help/dont-ask]) and brainstorming questions are discouraged (see [help/on-topic]). Raw idea generation isn't a good fit for this site. We do permit well-focused questions with limited possible multiple responses, but what you have now doesn't meet the expectations. It would help tremendously if you clearly defined what you mean by "4D" because, at best, it's only a mathematical thought experiment, not yet real science.

Comment: For inspiration, check Mage: the Ascension RPG which has the Correspondence Sphere. It allows manipulating space and manifesting various effects that twist, warp, or exploit it. For example, a normal gun might be made to fire in any direction, including back at the shooter. Because the bullet itself travels through a straight line, yet the whole path is warped such that it ends at a different angle than "straight ahead". Mage: the Awakening tabletop game has a similar type of magic in the Space Arcana.

Comment: Sorry, yes, @elemtilas is correct, I should've been clearer; I meant that if a question is grounded in a real-life concept, it requires less clarification on the part of the author, as life writes that part for them.  In this case, your "4th dimension" seems at odds with any higher-dimension concepts in physics, so we would need additional explanation of what _your_ "4th dimension" entailed in order to write worthwhile answers.

Comment: @jdunlop --- That I agree with!

Answer (score 3):

A 4D creature interacting with 3D creatures could do about as much as we could do if we were to intersct with 2D beings.

Now there may be some that say that we need at least three spatial dimensions for life. But handwave that away and imagine we had a world of animated stick people on a sheet of paper. Also we are able to cross that sheet without damaging it.

The stick people only see our 2D projection in the sheet. Also, no matter how much we twist the sheet, it seems flat to them.

So we can twist the sheet to connect ends and make infinite loops of their space, and connect distant points. You already imagined something like that when you said wormholes.

What else could we do? From outside the sheet, we can see the inside of any enclosed space they have. Like a box, or a house with all its doors closed... stick figures inside it cannot see those outside and vice versa. But we 3D creatures can see through everything that is in the sheet. We can also appear and disappeae from inside their closed spaces as if we were ghosts since we can cross the sheet from any point, so we could take a 2D diamond from the inside of a 2D safe without ever having to open that safe. No wormholing involved... though if we then place that diamond back in the sheet anywhere else it will seem like teleportation to the stick people, even though it isn't.

Last but not least, we could take an object out of the sheet, flip it horizontally, and place it back. For the stick people, it will seem like the object became the mirror image of itself. In 3D terms: someone might be pulled out of this 3D world, and if flipped and put back here, their insides are flipped. Suddenly someone who was left handed and had a tattoo on the left arm is now right handed and the tattoo is on their right arm. The person's heart would also be more on the right side of their chest. The liver and spleen would seem like they switched places.